# What should be the type of createReadStream in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, fs

I am trying to use typescript. What should be the **type of createReadStream**? I have found the types declaration following from `fs.d.ts` file from this [**DefinitelyTyped**
link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/fs.d.ts) on **github**

### UPDATE

what I am trying to do is **upload a file** from the **frontend**. On **backend**( basically node), I receive a **file object**. on **destructing** the file object, I get the following.

```
const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
```

Is there any way, I can use this type?

#### updated question

Now, how should I add the type of the **file** object that I receive in the
**function parameter** of the function given below?

```
export const processUpload = async (file, DestinationDir) {

}
```

### Type found in official `node/fs.d.ts` file

```
function createReadStream(path: PathLike, options?: string | {
        flags?: string;
        encoding?: string;
        fd?: number;
        mode?: number;
        autoClose?: boolean;
        /**
         * @default false
         */
        emitClose?: boolean;
        start?: number;
        end?: number;
        highWaterMark?: number;
    }): ReadStream;
```

### Code sample

```
export const processUpload = async (
  file:
    | PromiseLike<{
        createReadStream: /** WHAT SHOULD BE THE TYPE */;
        filename: string;
        mimetype: string;
        encoding: string;
      }>
    | {
        createReadStream: /** WHAT SHOULD BE THE TYPE */;
        filename: string;
        mimetype: string;
        encoding: string;
      },

  { DestinationDir = "default" }: { DestinationDir: string }
) => {
  const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;
  const stream = createReadStream();
  
  /** SOME CODE */ 

  return /*SOME RETURN TYPE*/
};
```

Comment: `npm install --save-dev @types/fs`

Comment: I tried, it seems package doesn't exist.

Comment: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/filesystem`

Comment: @ritaj, I found the link. but, It would be helpful if you can please share a snippet. thanks

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the text are a completely different. You're not asking what the type of `createReadStream` should be. You're asking if you can magically apply `createReadStream` to a specific file in some way. The answer is: No, not really. I mean, you *could* do this: `import * as fs from "fs"; const {filename, /*...*/} = await file; const createReadStream = fs.createReadStream.bind(fs, filename);` but it doesn't buy you anything useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please have a look at this once [example link](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-yoga/blob/master/examples/file-upload/index.ts)

Comment: That's from graphql-upload, not Node.js. (It may be a wrapper or bound version of the Node.js one as in the above, but...)

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use this:

```
import { ReadStream } from "fs-capacitor";

export interface FileUpload {
  createReadStream(): ReadStream;
  filename: string;
  mimetype: string;
  encoding: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`fs.createReadStream` returns a `ReadStream` object. Also, the TypeScript doesn't expect you to provide a type for `fs.createReadStream`.